# Using Finite Rank Operators to Prove that Compact Operators form an Ideal

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory, ideals, compact-operators

This is from Analytic K-Homology by Higson and Roe.

> Show that if $S$ is a rank one operator and $T$ is any operator, then $ST$ and $TS$ are rank one operators. Deduce that $\mathcal{K(H)}$ forms a closed ideal in $\mathcal{B(H)}$.

From [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4198074/628415), [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2146149/628415) these posts, it seems that my proof given below is too simple to be correct.

Proof:
Consider $K\in \mathcal{K(H)},\  T\in \mathcal{B(H)}$. $\exists$ finite rank operators $K_n$ such that $\| K_n-K\| \rightarrow 0$. $\implies \| K_n-K\|\|T\|\rightarrow 0$. $\implies \| K_nT-KT\|\rightarrow 0$. So $KT$ is the norm limit of the finite rank operators $K_nT$, hence compact.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What they are proving in those links is not what you have proved.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks to your comment my query is resolved.